# How to generate Lua iterators for C++ std::vector using SWIG?

Tags: c++, lua, swig

In `lua/std_vector.i` in SWIG 2.0.8 comment says:

> And no support for iterators & insert/erase

but maybe someone knows how to do it?

For example, it's possible to add `#`length operator by defining `__len` (it may work by accident, I've found it by trials and errors):

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%extend std::vector { int __len(void*) { return self->size(); } }
namespace std {
    %template(PointVector) vector<fityk::Point>;
}
```

I've tried similar trick with `__call`, but I'm stuck. SWIG wrapping gets in the way. I've tried using `%native`, but I couldn't make it work together with `%extend`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in SWIG template, but I managed to plug `__call` to SWIG-generated metatable from C++, after calling `luaopen_module`:

```
    SWIG_Lua_get_class_metatable(L_, PointVector);
    SWIG_Lua_add_function(L_, "__call", lua_vector_iterator);
```

So the vector can be used as iterator. A bit awkward 2 in 1, but works:

```
> = points
<PointVector userdata: 190FBE8>
> for n, p in points do print(n, p) end
0       (24.0154; 284; 16.8523)
1       (24.0541; 343; 18.5203)
```

The iterator returns index and value, like `enumerate()` in Python, and Lua passes the index back to the iterator next time (3rd arg on the stack). I haven't seen this behaviour documented, so I may rely on implementation details.

Here is the function used as `__call()`:

```
// SWIG-wrapped vector is indexed from 0. Return (n, vec[n]) starting from n=0.
static int lua_vector_iterator(lua_State* L)
{
    assert(lua_isuserdata(L,1)); // in SWIG everything is wrapped as userdata
    int idx = lua_isnil(L, -1) ? 0 : lua_tonumber(L, -1) + 1;

    // no lua_len() in 5.1, let's call size() directly
    lua_getfield(L, 1, "size");
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1); // arg: vector as userdata
    lua_call(L, 1, 1);   // call vector<>::size(this)
    int size = lua_tonumber(L, -1);

    if (idx >= size) {
        lua_settop(L, 0);
        return 0;
    }

    lua_settop(L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(L, idx); // index, to be returned
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);   // the same index, to access value
    lua_gettable(L, 1);     // value, to be returned
    lua_remove(L, 1);
    return 2;
}
```